# How to change the toolbar color of the Navigation Controller in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the color of my navigation bar. The following rgb is for a dark red color, but my nav bar turns white after the following code.

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:117 green:4 blue:32 alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is because the `CGFloat` values range from `0.0 to 1.0` not from `0 to 255`, and values above `1.0` are interpreted as `1.0`.

Here is the documentation:[UIColor](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 16):

Just do this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:117/255.0f green:4/255.0f blue:32/255.0f alpha:1];
```

Comment: I did this and now it's showing up as black instead of dark red

Comment: Looks like you are seeing either only white or only black for all the options...are you sure you dont have a B&W monitor? :) make sure you are not overriding this tint color somewhere else in your app.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. because when i use [UIColor redColor], or any other defined color it works fine

Comment: try something like that:    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:117/255.f green:4/255.f blue:32/255.f alpha:1];
    navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = color;

Comment: also - in which method are you calling this?

Comment: Haha, that's because it's converting the fractions to integers :) You need to specify fractions like this: `117/255.0f`  That way they stay as floats.

Comment: Note that it works differently on iOS 7: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18929980/1489823

Answer (score 6):

You have to divide each value for 255. Try:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:117/255.0f green:4/255.0f blue:32/255.0f alpha:1]
```

Comment: those values should be floats and not integers, otherwise the result will be an integer.

Comment: @JoãoPortela: I've edited answer so that the values remain as floats.

Answer (score 3):

I find that if you come from the web or from something like Photoshop, it is easier to work with Hexadecimal colors. You can use this macro for that:

```
//RGB color macro
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor \
colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 \
green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 \
blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

And use it like this:

```
self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xd8dadf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is funny. The real answer is that .tintColor sets the color for the navigation controller's  navigation Items (like a "Done" button).

Comment: It is only that way in recent iOS, not when the question was asked.