# How to change Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, uikit, uinavigationbar

How do I change the Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?

Basically I want to achieve something like the Twitter Nav Bar (updated Twitter for `iOS7` that is). I embedded-in a nav bar atop a `view controller`. All I want is to change the nav bar color to light blue along with the utility bar at the top. I can't seem to find an option in my `storyboard`.

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/18177010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177010/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7-or-6/18870519#18870519)

Comment: [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
this wll work from ios 7 onwards

Comment: follow  the this tutorial  http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Answer (score 320):

The behavior of `tintColor` for bars has changed in iOS 7.0. It no longer affects the bar's background.

From the documentation:

**barTintColor** [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/barTintColor)

The tint color to apply to the navigation bar background.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *barTintColor
```

**Discussion**
This color is made translucent by default unless you set the translucent property to `NO`.

**Availability**

Available in iOS 7.0 and later.

**Declared In**
[UINavigationBar.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html)

#### Code

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    // iOS 7.0 or later   
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}else {
    // iOS 6.1 or earlier
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

We can also use this to check iOS Version as mention in  [iOS 7 UI Transition Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // iOS 6.1 or earlier
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        // iOS 7.0 or later     
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    }
```

**EDIT**
Using xib

[image]

Comment: but where can I place this code?? Im very new to this hahah. I placed it within the app delegate and it really doesnt seem to be doing much. It builds just fine though.

Comment: inside viewController

Comment: I would put it in viewDidLoad in your viewController.

Comment: if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)

This would be better to test which iOS version you're running on, as stated by apple in the transition guide: 

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html

Comment: You can also use if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) vs the version number to check if you can set the barTintColor

Comment: You should put in viewWillAppear , it wouldnt reflect otherwise.

Comment: This one helped and +1 for sure!

Comment: Quite easier using the Storyboard!

Comment: any ideas why apple needed an extra prop when there is backgroundColor already?

Answer (score 130):

Doing what the original question asked—to get the old Twitter's Nav Bar look, blue background with white text—is very easy to do just using the Interface Builder in Xcode.

- Using the Document Outline, select your Navigation Bar.
- In the Attributes Inspector, in the Navigation Bar group, change the Style from Default to Black. This changes the background colour of the Navigation and Status bars to black, and their text to white. So the battery and other icons and text in the status bar will look white when the app is running.
- In the same Navigation Bar group, change the Bar Tint to the colour of your liking.
- If you have Bar Button items in your Navigation Bar, those will still show their text in the default blue colour, so in the Attributes Inspector, View group, change the Tint to White Colour.

That should get you what you want. Here is a screenshot that would make it easier to see where to make the changes.

[image: Where to make the necessary changes, including the result in iOS Simulator]

Note that changing only the Bar Tint doesn't change the text colour in the Navigation Bar or the Status Bar. The Style also needs to be changed.

Comment: Selecting black for iOS 9 is deprecated, any chance of an updated answer

Comment: @Rob85 I am not in front of Xcode right now, but when Xcode 7 (with iOS 9) was released I verified that these instructions were still up-to-date. Make sure that the Navigation Bar is selected, the black style should be in the attributes inspector of the Navigation Bar.

Comment: @Rob85 I've checked Apple's Developer website, and styles `Default` and `Black` are still available in iOS 9. The deprecated ones are `BlackOpaque` and `BlackTranslucent`, which were replaced by a combination of `Black` style and the Translucent tick-box. [UIBarStyle on Apple's Developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIBarStyle)

Comment: Sorry @alondono you are absolutely correct, i was clicking on the navigation bar on the Navigation Controller not in document outline thats why i couldn't see it . The black that i am seeing deprecated was on the simulated metrics->status bar. Thanks for your replies

Comment: @Rob85 Cool! Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: This answer still works.  I like configuring the visuals using visual editor, and leave the code to do actual logic.

Answer (score 79):

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

// *barTintColor* sets the background color
// *tintColor* sets the button's color
```

Comment: And where exactly can I put this code?? Sorry for the newbie question there hahah

Comment: the code can be placed in the - (void)viewDidLoad method of the navigation controller

Comment: In iOS 9, setting the barTintColor to black will make the time, device name and battery black too so you can't see them. To avoid this, instead of using barTintColor, use self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

Answer (score 46):

In a Navigation based app you can put the code in AppDelegate. A more detailed code could be:

```
// Navigation bar appearance (background and title)

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor titleColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontNAme" size:titleSize], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor barColor]];

// Navigation bar buttons appearance

[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor textBarColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, shadowColor, NSShadowAttributeName, [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontName" size:titleSize], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
```

Comment: add `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor barColor]];` for iOS 7

Answer (score 25):

In `viewDidLoad`, set:

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Change ( `blueColor` ) to whatever color you'd like.

Answer (score 18):

For swift change navigation bar color:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
```

change title font,size, color:

```
self.title = "title"
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 30)!
    ]
```

Answer (score 14):

In iOS 7 you must use the -barTintColor property:

```
navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor barColor];
```

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use a hex code, here is the best way to do so.

First, define this at the top of your class:

```
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

Then inside the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions", put this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0x00b0f0)];
```

Put you hex code in place of the 00b0f0.

Comment: [UINavigationBar appearance] was very helpful.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to support ios6 and ios7 then you get that particular light blue using this in your **UIViewController**:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:174/255.0f blue:235/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    }else{
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:89/255.0f green:174/255.0f blue:235/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }
}
```

Comment: On iOS 7: -self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor is the bar color AND -self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor is the buttons text color (back, done...).

Answer (score 10):

It's actually easier than the answers I've seen here:

```
1) Just make sure you select the navigation bar on the Navigation control. 
2) Select the color you want in the bar tint.
3) You have other options too, and/or individually on each view (just play with it).
```

I hope this helps somebody. I didn't like the answers I saw. I like to keep my code as clean as possible. Not saying that it's wrong to do it programmatically, but there are people out there like me....this is for you guys.
[image: Changing color of the navigation bar]

Comment: Thanks, I had changed this months ago while playing around and couldn't figure out how to change it back!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help someone

Comment: I think this is the most straight forward  answer! Thx

Comment: No problem. Glad it's still helpful

Answer (score 5):

```
//You could place this code into viewDidLoad
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //change the nav bar colour
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //change the background colour
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
 }   
//Or you can place it into viewDidAppear
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //change the nav bar colour
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    //change the background colour
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To make Rajneesh071's code complete, you may also want to set the navigation bar's title color (and font, if you want) since the default behavior changed from iOS 6 to 7:

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7)
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    NSMutableDictionary *textAttributes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:mainNavController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes];
    [textAttributes setValue:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:UITextAttributeTextColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes;
}
else
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add only This code in your `ViewContorller` **or** in your `AppDelegate`

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0)
{
    //This is For iOS6
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
else
{
    //This is For iOS7
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In a navigation based application you can change color

```
NSArray *ver = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
if ([[ver objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 7) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:86.0/255.0 blue:138.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
} else {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:19.0/255.0 green:86.0/255.0 blue:138.0/255.0 alpha:1];
}
```

Comment: Changing the tintColor property in iOS7 has no longer the effect of changing the bars background color. Tint color in iOS7 only affects the text color of the BarButtonItems etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define _kisiOS7 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)


  if (_kisiOS7)
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIcolor redcolor]];
    }
    else
    {
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIcolor blackcolor]];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIcolor graycolor]];
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This question and these answers are helpful. With them I was able to set my desired dark blue `navigationBar` color with white title and button text.

But I also needed to change the clock, carrier, signal strength, etc. to white. Black just didn't contrast enough with the dark blue.

I may have overlooked that solution in one of the previous answers, but I was able to make that change by adding this line to my top level `viewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

Comment: `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` works, but it seems the correct enum for `setBarStyle:` is `UIBarStyleBlack`

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For Color :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

For Image

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBar_320X44.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```