# How do I change the color of my text in my UINavigationBar on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

How do I change the color of my text in my UINavigationBar on iOS 7? I want it white instead of black:

[image]

Comment: See `UINavigationBar textTitleAttributes`

Comment: I've answer to somthing similar before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934411/2796060

Answer (score 13):

If you're ok with a global change, you can put this in your App Delegate:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes];
```

Comment: Why the old syntax? `@{UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor whiteColor]}`

Comment: UITextAttributeTextColor seems to be deprecated in iOS 7

Comment: For iOS 7 and so forth, use NSForegroundColorAttributeName instead of UITextAttributeTextColor.