# IOS7 UINavigationBar black background

Tags: colors, background, uinavigationbar, ios7

Does anybody know, how I can make the UINavigationBar solid black in IOS7? Default it is white, and I need it black.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting only iOS 7 you can use:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:(UIColor *)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way that creates a black UIImage programmatically and sets it for the UINavigationBar's appearance:

```
UIView *background = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 568, 44)];
background.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(background.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[background.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *backgroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();        

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage
                                           forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

found it by myself. Go into storyboard-designer, select the ViewController, go to attribute inspector and change Top Bar from inferred to 'Opaque black navigation bar'

Comment: Interface-Builder unfortunately only provides a simulated appearance (look at the label, it says "Simulated Metrics"). You need to set this in code (per ViewController) or in your info.plist (per application).