# IOS7 navigatinBar tintColor change in popover

Tags: ios, ios7, uipopovercontroller, navigationcontroller

I developed iPad application. I'm opening some screens in popover with navigation controller. But I did not change navigationcontroller tint color in IOS 7. How can I change this color. thanx

[image]

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:airportsSearch] autorelease];
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
self.popOver=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

self.popOver.delegate                    = self;
[self.popOver setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(285, 370)];

[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:tempButton.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES];
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Comment: @Rajneesh071 this method don't work :(

Comment: can you send me your sample code ?

Comment: There is sample code on question, thnx

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The magical word here is `barStyle`, you need to do the following if you need it black:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

And if you want to change its color:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

Comment: @null thank you very much. I had a custom UINavigationController class where I set the same properties beside barStyle. All my navigationControllers worked fine and they have set UIBarStyleDefault in the storyboard. Only my NavigationBars inside Popovers were translucent and the barTintColor didn't change anything. Only the tintColor got set. But as soon as I set the barStyle to Black the problems were resolved!

Comment: For some reason setting the barStyle to UIBarStyleBlack removes the navigation bar shadow... May be you have an advice how to fix that?

Comment: I think removing the translucent causes this, may this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19226998/1262634 will help.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the NavigationBarStyle to UIBarStyleBlack also worked for me, but only via the Storyboard.

I tried

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

as well as

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil] setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
```

in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions AppDelegate method. But nothing changed. Only changing the BarStyle of the NavigationControllers NavigationBar inside the **Storyboard** worked.