# How to change navigation bar background/color in UIPopoverController in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller

As titled, in iOS7, How to change navigation bar background/color in UIPopoverController?

I'm using the following way, but does not work

```
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:packListViewController];
    [navController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    if (_packListPickerPopover == nil) {
        _packListPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
        _packListPickerPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(950, 345);
    }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8490261/change-color-navigation-controller-in-a-popover

Comment: @Jatin, Thanks, i went through that topic before this thread. And I'm wondering whether there's some simple ways to do that (in that topic, it's too complicated)

Comment: @Jacky actually this question is probably more closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095195/ios7-navigatinbar-tintcolor-change-in-popover and the top answer worked for me

Answer (score 7):

iOS 7 onwards, you can use `backgroundColor` property of `UIPopoverController`.

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) UIColor *backgroundColor NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Usage example:

```
    if ([self.popoverVC respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)]) {   // Check to avoid app crash prior to iOS 7
        self.popoverVC.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
```

**Note** - As of now (iOS 7.0.3), in some cases (like set color using colorWithPatternImage:), the simulator doesn't honor the color but *on device it works fine*.