# IOS7 Status bar change to black after search is active

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using UISearchBar as header of UITableView. UISearchBar style is UISearchBarStyleMinimal. And when search is active, status bar change to black. How to fix that?

Before search is active

[image: Before search is active]

Search is active

[image: Search is active]

Comment: Please go through this link may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678881/how-to-change-status-bar-text-color-in-ios-7

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Comment: The problem is i want to set status bar as default style. LightContent is ok but all most view controller in my app using default style.

Comment: The solution is : self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Answer (score 21):

you just need to do this:

```
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, but the question is why do we need to do this?  It seems like a bug on Apple's part.