# Active UISearchBar makes status bar background black

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uistatusbar

I have a `UISearchBar` at the top of `UITableView` which works great. I've been trying to customise its appearance and there is an issue when the search bar is active - it turns the status bar background colour to black. I tried the suggestions in [IOS7 Status bar change to black after search is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129540/ios7-status-bar-change-to-black-after-search-is-active) but it didn't work for me.

[image: Example showing the black status bar]

App is iOS 7-only. `UISearchBar` is to to Minimal Search Style and Default Bar Style, translucent and default barTintColor. I've customised its appearance in my AppDelegate as follows:

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBarTintColor:AAColorInputBorder];
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:AAColorInputBorder];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; 
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
 setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [UIColor whiteColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                         [UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:16], NSFontAttributeName,
                         nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir" size:14]];
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to change the status bar background color? I want it to match the colour of the `UISearchBar`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hack I use to extend the UISearchBar color

on viewDidLoad()

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

    [self removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar];
```

method:

```
- (void) removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
           [subview removeFromSuperview];
           break; //To avoid an extra loop as there is only one UISearchBarBackground
        } else {
           [self removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:subview];
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Unfortuantely didn't fix it for me. I presume this would go under `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I had forgotten to include a method. Also, I did not come up with this solution; I found it a while ago here and can't find the original post