# UISearchBar changing status bar color to white

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar and for some odd reason whenever the search bar is tapped on the status bar color changes from black to white. I don't want the status bar color to change. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's the structure of the `UIViewController` that contains this `UISearchBar`?

Comment: @mbm29414 What do you mean by the "structure"?

Comment: Is it a `UISearchBar` added to a standard `UIViewController`? Is it a `UISearchDisplayController`? Trying to get a feel for where the code might go to set the `UIStatusBarStyle`.

Comment: In agreement with @mbm29414 . Check out [Search Bar appearance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISearchBar.html)

Comment: @mbm29414 ahh, it's in a `UITableViewController` with `UISearchBarDelegate`. Thanks

Comment: @LouisTur I looked at Search Bar Appearance and couldn't find anything on status bar color

Comment: Is your `UITableViewController` embedded in a `UINaivgationController`?

Comment: The accepted answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129540/ios7-status-bar-change-to-black-after-search-is-active?answertab=votes#tab-top) seems to indicate that the `UISearchBar` sends a call to its "parent" `UINavigationController` when it begins editing. Can you try doing what it suggests and report back?

Comment: Oh, sorry I misread the post. A really good resource is [App Coda](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/). You may need to implement `preferredStatusBarStyle`... maybe even in conjunction with `UISearchBarStyle` settings

Comment: @LouisTur It worked! Setting the preferredStatusBarStyle somehow fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @mbm29414 I just fixed it, I set the preferredStatusBarStyle and that seemed to get it to work! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sure thing. <15 characters>.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129540/ios7-status-bar-change-to-black-after-search-is-active?answertab=votes#tab-top) seems to indicate that the `UISearchBar` sends a call to its "parent" `UINavigationController` when it begins editing.

Therefore, you seem to have 2 options:

1. You could simply override the `tintColor` for the `UINavigationController` for you `UITableViewController`, or
2. You could write a simple `UINavigationController` subclass that overrides `-preferredStatusBarStyle`, returning the desired style.

It looks like #1 gives you what you need with minimal fuss/code.

Comment: I think you can override `preferredStatusBarStyle` from any view controller, it's directly accessible without the need for subclassing.

Comment: @LouisTur That hasn't been true in my experience, but I'm willing to give it a shot.

Comment: I'm overriding `preferredStatusBarStyle` from a `UIViewController` that is contained within a `UINavigationController`, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is the following:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

and implement this function:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleDarkContent;
}
```