# iOS 6 app on iOS 7 Device with Navigation bar hidden

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode4.6

I copied iOS 7 sdk to xcode 4.6 sdks directory. Now I can set Base SDK to either iOS 6 or iOS 7. I can successfully run iOS 6 apps on

I am running an iOS 6 app on iOS 7 device using Xcode 4.6. Base SDK is set to 6.1.
Her is some code from AppDelegate:

```
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];

navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

window.rootViewController = navigationController;
```

Now I have a strange problem on iOS 7 device that status bar doesn't show anything and its transparent.

Previously I installed another app on iOS 7 device with Base SDK set as 6.1, It was working perfectly but in that application NavigationBar wasn't hidden.

What I get when I run the app(the one whose code is above) it shows as this:

[image]

and

[image]

I have tried everything to make status bar solid but its not working. Navigation bar shown in these images is an image view and default navigation bar is hidden. I wonder how its working in another app of mine in which navigation bar is not hidden.

Please Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979837/cant-hide-ios-7-status-bar/18980833#18980833