# How to change the color of the status bar?

Tags: colors, ios7, uistatusbar

I have a quick question for you.
Is it posible to change the color of the status bar in iOS 7 (Like Facebook app)
And is it also possible to increase the transparency of the status bar ?

Thank you in advance,
Davy

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0)?YES:NO) {
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}else{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"previousImage.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Or you can also do this:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

if you are not showing navigation bar in your application.

Comment: thank you for your quick response
I have to put this code in the viewDidLoad?

Comment: yes you can put it in viewDidLoad  but before that you should have botj images as newimage with size 320x64 and previousimage with size 320x44.

Answer (score 0):

You can change navigation bar color to change status bar color.

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```