# Present a navigation view from view controller - IOS 7

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios7

I got an error when I need to present a navigation controller from view controller like below:

"Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!"

The code as below:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"NavMain" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * mainViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
mainViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:mainViewController animated:YES completion:NO];
```

How to fix the bugs or does I had any error when implement storyboard?
I use two storyboard from `main.storyboard` to `NavMain.storyboard`

Comment: Just trying to clarify are you trying to add a navigation controller from navmain storyboard to a UIViewController in the main storyboard. May I ask what is the reasoning behind wanting to do this?

Comment: When start to load application, I want a loading page (UIViewController) to download some data. After finish download, I need to present another view which is navigation controller for login page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that `self`'s view hasn't loaded yet. You want to call this code after the view has loaded. So put it in:

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```