# Change navigation bar tint color iOS 7.

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, uicolor, appdelegate

I know how to change navigation bat tint colour in iOS 6:

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

I'm adding this code in APPDelegate page.
Now I want to do this in iOS 7 but above code is not working.
I searched on net. I got a solution. By adding below function to every page I can change navigation color.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

But I need a function which can add to APPDelegate function.
Please help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can add bellow code in appdelegate.m

```
  if your app is navigation based

 // for background color
  [nav.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

 // for change navigation title and button color
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,  [UIFont fontWithName:@"FontNAme" size:20], NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Answer (score 14):

Why not to use `setBarTintColor` for appearance proxy, you can do this:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) 
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
else
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
}
```

Comment: The problem with appearance is it is global. This doesn't work for me as it causes tons of bugs all over with incorrect colors on navigation bars after I run this code. I need to set it on the actual instance....

Comment: What ray said. Using respondsToSelector for version checking may be better.

Comment: If you need to change only the current navigation bar's appearance you could use:
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor anyColor];`
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor anyColor];`

Answer (score 2):

Using respondsToSelector for version checking may be better.

```
if ([self.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBarTintColor:)]) {
    [self.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
 } else {
    [self.navigationBar setTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:129/255.0 green:200/255.0 blue:244/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, for me, I wanted to change tint color for the Cancel and Send buttons, when the e-mail pops up. And it worked great.

```
(UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UINavigationBar.self])).tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];

Comment: He doesn't want to change the navigation bar translucency