# Different ways to check iOS version?

Tags: ios

I've seen various methods of checking the iOS version of the device.

From some example in Apple Documentation :

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
    // < = 6.1
} else {
    // > = 7
}
```

And from many examples over SO / Internet :

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

What is the difference between `NSFoundationVersionNumber` and `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]` ?

And which one should we use ?

Comment: This answer will cover all of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7848772/1091539

Comment: Go with NSFoundationVersionNumber

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7/18929980#18929980

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They basically provide the same answer, however, NSFoundationVersionNumber is better, as no string parsing of the systemVersion is needed.

Comment: My SDKs only include `NSFoundationVersionNumber` and `NAAppKitVersionNumber` only to iOS 7.1 and Mac OS 10.9.2. I navigated to the 8.1 resp. 10.10 SDK --> Frameworks --> Foundation --> NSObjcRuntime.h