# Changes in Nav Bar/Status Bar after Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, tabbarcontroller

I'm just wondering could anyone tell me why the navigation bar and status bar in an app different after it has passed through a navigation controller?

The app I'm working on is a Tab Bar Controller app that has one section with a table view ('More' tab). This view controller that holds the table view is embedded in a navigation controller. The navigation bar and status bar reach further down the page in the 'More' tab and I feel it is something to do with the navigation controller.

I would love if all the tabs had a matching style for the navigation bar and status bar. Apologies if I am not describing this clearly, I can't post images yet as I am just starting out with development and SO.

I suppose I am asking:

- How to change the appearance of status and navigation bar in a Navigation Controller?

  Any help I get will be gratefully received. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution you search for:

Question 1:
[How to change the appearance of status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17768797/1091539)

Question 2:
[How to change the appearance of navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18929980/1091539) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934411/1091539)

Comment: Thank you very much for that. Do you know why the navigation/status bar is longer than in the other view controllers? I have tried to set them to the same height through the size inspector but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks again