# How to make an iOS Dark-theme

Tags: ios, themes

I want to make my app a dark-theme, a black transluscent, or whatever it's called. It is currently used in apps likeTweetbot, Apple Maps, and iStudiez Pro. How could I attempt to do this?

Here's the [link](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/istudiez-pro/id310636441) to an example picture: (iStudiez Pro, Screenshot 1)

[image]

Comment: I would start with some additional research, come up with some designs, and then attempt to implement them.

Answer (score 0):

For doing custom maps I believe your best bet is to use [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can select the Navigation Bar in the storyboard and then change the style to Black. This produced more of a dark grey color in my tests. If you want an actual black you can set the Bar Tint to black. The black theme will change the Title and status bar icon colors to white.

[image]

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26421764/3681880).