# NavigationBar Title Color changes by itself in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

Why NavigationBar title color changes by itself sometimes to black and sometimes to white. Any ideas how to prevent this.

Thanks

Comment: More info needed! meanwhile you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7

Answer (score 0):

I think problem maybe is background color of the view (in iOS 7.x)