# Setting the same background colour on UIStatusBar as UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I am looking to set a background colour on the `UIStatusBar` in my app and I want it to match the background colour of the `UINavigationBar`, same as the `Facebook` and `Instagram` apps.

I tried adding this function to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in my `AppDelegate`:

```
-(void) setStatusBarColour{

    #define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
        UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,self.window.rootViewController.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
        view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor lightGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6];
        [self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:view];
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On iOS 7 background colour of status bar inherits from colour of navigation bar.
So You can do something like this

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];`

And check out this link:http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/

Comment: Ah nice. I was playing around with this function and was also setting the backgroundColor property of the navigation bar instead of the bar tint colour. But it works now. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write extra code for that. once you change color of navigationBar, statusBar will adapt the same color & tints for the fonts automatically.

**How to change color of navigationBar?**

Follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-do-i-change-the-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7)

and this is Facebook bar color Hex code : #3B5998

So your code would be :

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:59 green:89 blue:152 alpha:1]];
```