# UIPickerView to be same color as navigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar, uipickerview

I have an app with a UIPickerView that comes on screen when needed. I would like it to be the same color as the default navigationBar which is a little transparent, you can see through it but not enough to obscure what is on the navigationBar.

There may be a simple solution and if there is great! I'm new to the game.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Yossi did you even read his question?! :/

Comment: @JKX You may want to add `UIVisualEffectView` thats blurs the views below it as the picker's background view.

Comment: Great! Ended up going with the UIVisualEffectView... worked exactly how I envisaged! Thank you

Comment: you might want to refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26421764/4757258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to @ChristianSchorr  I used UIVisualEffectView to achieve my goal

```
UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
        [self.tableStations addSubview:visualEffectView];
        pickerSort.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,originalPickerFrame.size.width,originalPickerFrame.size.height);
        visualEffectView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,originalPickerFrame.size.width,originalPickerFrame.size.height - 64);
```

Worked for I needed