# change navigation bar color of specific controller

Tags: ios, swift

I have set a color of my Navigation bar in `Appdelegate` so my app uses same color for all the navigation appearing in different screens. But Now for one or two controllers I want to change the navigation color. I used this code in `viewDidLoad` of specific controller but It isn't working

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

I have tried this code in `viewWillAppear` function too but still it doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is not `backgroundColor`, but rather `barTintColor`.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use tint color

```
  [nav.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. well As I am working on swift so I can't mark your answer correct But I know you were the first answering the right solution