# How do you change the title color for a view controller pushed onto the stack?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

From a UITableView I am pushing another view controller with another UITableView onto the stack using this code:

```
// allocate and create instance of categories view controller
TJKCategoriesViewController *categoriesViewController = [[TJKCategoriesViewController alloc] init];

// push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:categoriesViewController animated:YES];
```

When I am in the viewDidLoad method for the TJKCategoriesViewContoller I am changing the title using this code:

```
self.title = @"Categories";
```

This works just fine. However the "Categories" title is coming out the color of black and I would like it to be a different color.  I've tried things like tintColor, but self.title doesn't have this property.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your viewDidLoad method:

```
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: NSForegroundColorAttributeName, NSFontAttributeName, nil];
NSArray *objs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIColor redColor], [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.0f], nil];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objs forKeys:keys];
```

You can customize the font and the color

Answer (score 2):

You can create a UILabel and set it to UINavigationItem's titleView. See Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/titleView

Some codes:

```
- (void)setMyTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.view.bounds.size.width - 100, 44)];
    titleLabel.text = title;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16];
    titleLabel.textColor = ...
    ...
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked too.  I don't have enough reputation points to increment the useful counter yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tintColor` property of the NavigationBar:

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];`

If you want to make `tintColor` changes to be global, you can use the NavigationBar appearance proxy.

`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor: [UIColor blueColor]];`