# Changing the Navigation Bar Tint changes the color not correctly

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uinavigationbar

I tried doing it like described in [How to change Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7) but unfortunatley it does not seem to work for me.

The color only changes to a light version. Since a screenshot describes it better than a thousand words here you go:

[image: Bar[![]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
use this code work for me 

[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:95/255.f green:154/255.f blue:201/255.f alpha:1]];
```

using storyboard

[image]

Comment: Added the Xamarin equivalent code of your snippet but result is the same (light red color)