# How to edit the default navigationBar?

Tags: ios, storyboard

This is the UI image, I want to create the searchBar like this:

[image]

But, however, in storyboard, I can not get this.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

To achieve the effect I want, how can I do it?

I want to change my default navigation bar to the upper, which have a search bar on it.

---

**Update**

If I in inspect choose the `Top Bar` to `None`, I get this below navigationBar with a transparent bar.(ignore the its below red view, I add that.)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change Navigation Bar color in iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve what you are looking for from storyboard. You must programmatically add the search bar to the `UINavigationBar`'s `navigationItem`. Like so,

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar() // Your Search bar
self.navigationController.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

The only other thing you might consider is that this shouldnt be a `UINavigationBar` but instead a `UIView` with a `UISearchBar` subview. That you could put together in storyboard.

---

**EDIT** (answer for comment)

"and the cancel button how can I add it?"

This you can easily add. Something like this:

```
let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonTapped))
self.navigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = cancelButton
```

---

"can I hide my navigationBar in storyboard?"

Yes. Select the view controller in which you'd like to hide the `UINavigationBar`, select the inspector pane, and for "Top Bar" choose "None".

[image]

Comment: and the cancel button how can I add it?

Comment: can I hide my navigationBar in storyboard?

Comment: Yes you can hide navigation bar.

Comment: @three-blocks I updated my answer once again to answer you comment.

Comment: @BrandonA See my update question, bro, if I set none, there is a issue.

Comment: @three-blocks I see your updated answer but not sure what your issue is. Are you saying that there is still a transparent UINavigationBar? It must have been a subview programmatically. Can you paste the code where you are adding this?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is already given by Brandon, now if you don't want to do code work you can create your own navigation bar from storyboard. Do below steps

1. Hide the native navigation bar on the navigation controller.
2. Now take a view with leading, trailing, top 0 space and constant height 64.
3. Add search bar button title whatever you want and give constraints as per your requirement and take outlets and do what you want.

For more query you can ask.